# How to connect to PostgreSQL in Apache flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL via Apache Flink, but I don't get data from the table, neither those that are already in the table, nor new ones.

Tried 2 options:

1. At first I tried it this way, based on [this](https://ververica.github.io/flink-cdc-connectors/master/content/connectors/postgres-cdc.html) example:

```
SourceFunction<String> postgresSourceBuilder = new PostgreSQLSource.Builder<String>()
        .hostname("ip")
        .port(5432)
        .database("database")
        .tableList("table")
        .username("user")
        .password("password")
        .deserializer(new JsonDebeziumDeserializationSchema())
        .build();
 
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.addSource(postgresSourceBuilder).print().setParallelism(1);
env.execute();
```

Judging by the dashboard in pgAdmin 4, Debezium establishes a connection to the database, but, at the same time, records from the table are not displayed in the logs, neither those that existed nor new ones.

What am I doing wrong in this case, maybe "print()" should not output records?

2. I tried to make the following query via Linq SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTest (
  id INT,
  FIRST NUMERIC(6),
  LAST NUMERIC(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
   'connector' = 'jdbc',
   'url' = 'jdbc:postgresql://ip/database',
   'table-name' = 'table',
   'username'='user',
   'password'='password'
);
 
SELECT * FROM MyTest;
```

After that, existing records are displayed from the table, but new ones are not.

How to use this method in a Java application, maybe to execute a query through the "ExecuteSQL()" method? How to make the data read repeatedly?